# Search all windows in a Notepad++ session

Tags: windows, notepad++, search, tabs

I've recently discovered and much more quickly became spoiled by a brand new chrome extension called "[Search all tabs](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/search-all-tabs/ndfnfhnlgoocpbbjjjfmiojdfcgcfomn?hl=en)." Now whenever I work with any application that is heavy with tabs, all I want to do is use the "Search all X" feature of that application. For example, I have fallen for multiple times looking for a Notepad++ "search all tabs" feature and I forget no that was chrome lol. And then I realize the way to do it in Notepad++ is to go to toolbar > Window > Windows and then manually locate the open tab I am looking for. It would be great if there was a tab search feature in Notepad++. Does anyone know if there is a plugin in Notepad++ that does this exactly as the chrome extension? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I well understand, but, is that what you want?

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- <kbd>Find All in All Opened Documents</kbd>

**Screenshot:**

[image]

Comment: no not exactly. What I am saying is more like if you have "random_file_name_sgh_1", "random_file_name_eaf_2", ... all the 
 way to a nth file named  'random_file_name_lkj_n" opened, search all tabs for name x and provide a list of closest matches. Actually, it would be nice not all if the plugin did a file name search but also content search - so yea your suggestion would be a nice inclusion in what I  am asking. Try the chrome extension, it will show what I mean.